# fillna() is not replacing NaN values even after using inplace=True

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fillna

I am trying to replace NaN value in my 'price' column of my dataset, I tried using:

```
avg_price = car.groupby('make')['price'].agg(np.mean) # calculating average value of the price of each car company model

new_price= car['price'].fillna(avg_price,inplace=True)

car['price']=new_price
```

The code runs well without any error, but on checking, I can still see the NaN values in the dataset. Dataset snap shot is attached below:

[image: This is my original dataset as well as after running fillna() its the same]

Comment: Remove `car['price']=new_price`

Comment: I also tried running the replace(), but the below error:

car['price']=car['price'].replace(np.nan,avg_price,inplace=True)

Error:

ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace

Comment: Have you tried removing `car['price']=new_price` and then running?

Comment: @Luke  I tried removing the car['price']=new price line, still unable to see the changes in my datataset

Comment: Post the output of `df.isnull().values.any()` in your question before and after running your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to fill the `NaN` with a grouped (by make) average? Will this work?

```
df.loc[df.price.isnull(), 'price'] = df.groupby('make').price.transform('mean')
```